# How to load multiple versions of same dependency with SystemJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, systemjs

We're creating a portal that consists of multiple widgets. Each widget can use its own stack, as long as it's all JS, CSS and HTML that comes out.

Suppose the portal uses angular 1.2 and some widget uses angular 1.5.
The widget + its dependencies are loaded via SystemJS but in the end when the portal screen is loaded in the browser, the angular version of the portal is used (= the angular global variable points to that angular version).
Is there a way to use the widget's version of angular inside the widget's HTML and the portal's version of angular inside portal HTML code width SystemJS?

Comment: I have a similar question... Any updates?